# Convert timestamp to date format

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to convert timestamp (NSTimeInterval) to date format. I'm getting the correct current date (day-month-year) but the time is not right. Here is my code. How do I fix it to get the current time correctly? Thanks in advance.

```
- (NSString*)formatTimestamp:(NSTimeInterval)timeStamp
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:timeStamp];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz"];
    NSString *dateString=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [formatter release];
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain "the time is not right" more. What happens? What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: The time is not current time. For example, NSLog's time is 2012-05-15 15:27:26.505, but this is what I got from my code: 15-05-2012 22:01:15:856 PDT. I want to get the same time as the timestamp from NSLog.

Comment: Which variable are you printing with NSLog?  Are you printing "date" with NSLog, as well as the returned value from the method?

Comment: I'm printing the returned value from the method. NSLog(@"Time:%@", [self formatTimestamp:event.timestamp]); where event.timestamp is the timestamp of the touch from - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { //event.timestamp is obtained and printed from here!}

Comment: where is the timestamp argument for your method coming from? Is it from the same machine, or a different machine altogether? What is generating it?

Comment: It's the timestamp of a touch from
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     NSLog(@"Time:%@", [self formatTimestamp:event.timestamp]); }

Comment: If you try it simulator you get wrong time because i guess they guess cupertino time
But if you try in device you will get correct time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood something but I think your comparison is not right...

`NSLog`'s time is *current time* and `UIEvent`'s `timestamp` is *the number of seconds since system startup* (and you add it to current time with `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:]`)...

If you want absolute datetime of an `UIEvent` you need to get system startup date first, which is not so easy... and then add `UIEvent`'s `timestamp`.

You can use

```
lastRebootTime = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:-[self secondsSinceLastReboot]];
```

with

```
- (NSTimeInterval)secondsSinceLastReboot
{
    // get the timebase info -- different on phone and OSX
    mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
    mach_timebase_info(&info);

    // get the time
    uint64_t absTime = mach_absolute_time();

    // apply the timebase info
    absTime *= info.numer;
    absTime /= info.denom;

    // convert nanoseconds into seconds
    return (NSTimeInterval) ((double)absTime / 1000000000.0);
}
```

Cf. [Generating iPhone UIEvent Timestamps](http://davepeck.org/2010/03/08/generating-iphone-uievent-timestamps/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You are absolutely right. I misunderstood UIEvent's timestamp, which is actually the number of seconds since system startup. Your solution works well, but I can get "secondsSinceLastReboot" from this: NSTimeInterval secondsSinceStartup =[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime];

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know this function (iOS4+ only).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to set the time zone?

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"YourTimeZone"];
[foprmatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

Comment: Yes, I did try [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"]]; however, the time doesn't look right. For example, NSLog's time is 2012-05-15 15:27:26.505, and this is what I got from my code: 15-05-2012 22:01:15:856 PDT.